# PDF Forms calculating time between start and end time / pdf not getting calculated form values

Tags: forms, pdf

I'm using a form and I want to have the time between two times calculated.  That part works - but I'm having problems getting the data after input has been calculated.

When you enter a time in hh:MM tt format - I have it so that it's calculated and output in HH:MM format already.  It doesn't accept that input however - it just tries to use whatever is originally put in the form.  This is currently how I'm capturing data from the two fields I need to take data from.  I can take this and have people use military time, but I'd prefer to just take input from the hh:MM tt format.

```
var hrsStart = parseInt(this.getField("sTime").value.split(":")[0]);
var minStart = parseInt(this.getField("sTime").value.split(":")[1]);
var hrsEnd = parseInt(this.getField("stTime").value.split(":")[0]);
var minEnd = parseInt(this.getField("stTime").value.split(":")[1]);
```

This is how I'm calculating data input into the two fields.

```
var time = this.getField("stTime");

var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1].toLowerCase();

if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;

this.getField("stTime").value = (sHours +':'+sMinutes);
```

Is my answer Validation?

I've also tried to do getHours / getMinutes but the values come up unresolved.

EDIT:

The following section of code correctly calculates the time inbetween to input times AND dates.  This is important because the date is required YOU WILL NEED TO INCLUDE A DATE.  This is how I solved my issue - thanks in part to some help I got!  Hope this is helpful to someone down the line.

```
var strStart = this.getField("sTime1.5").value;
var strEnd = this.getField("stTime1.5").value;
strStart = strStart + " 1/1/70";
strEnd = strEnd + " 1/1/70";
if(strStart.length && strEnd.length)
 {
   var timeStart = util.scand("h:MM tt m/d/yy", strStart);
   var timeEnd = util.scand("h:MM tt m/d/yy", strEnd);
   if (timeEnd < timeStart) {
   var strEnd = this.getField("stTime1.5").value
   var strEnd = strEnd + " 1/2/70";
   var timeEnd = util.scand("h:MM tt m/d/yy", strEnd);
   var diff = timeEnd - timeStart;
   var oneHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
   var timeleft = (diff/oneHour);
 }
 var diff = timeEnd - timeStart;
 var oneHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
 var timeleft = (diff/oneHour);
 event.value = timeleft.toFixed(2);

 } else {
 event.value = " ";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Date(string) constructor instead of parsing manually? It would be something like this: `var time = new Date(this.getField("stTime").toString());`. Once you do that, you can use all the methods and properties from the Date class, like getMinutes(), getSeconds() etc.

Comment: I get Invalid Date back.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a date to the begining of the string. See here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15. They say that the format allows date-only values, or date-time values, but they say nothing about time-only values...

Comment: I gave this a shot, and also gave dateFormat a shot and it gets an error somewhere.  Adobe PDF's debugger is useless or at least is useless to me so I can't give you an error back.

Comment: can you add to your question a few samples of strings you are trying to parse with the Date constructor? I will give them a try later when I have time

Comment: `var time = this.getField("stTime").value;`
`dateFormat(time,"h:MM TT");`

Comment: `var time = this.getField("stTime").value;`
`dateFormat(time,"h:MM TT");` error
`var time = new Date(dateFormat(this.getField("stTime"),"h:MM TT").toString());` error
`var time = new Date(this.getField("stTime").toString());` invalid date
`var time = new Date(this.getField("stTime"),"h:MM TT").toString());` invalid date
Sorry - stepped away for a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following section of code correctly calculates the time inbetween to input times AND dates. This is important because the date is required YOU WILL NEED TO INCLUDE A DATE - I did mine as static because this is submitted daily, and the date is irrelevant at this time. This is how I solved my issue - thanks in part to some help I got! Hope this is helpful to someone down the line.

```
var strStart = this.getField("sTime1.5").value;
var strEnd = this.getField("stTime1.5").value;
strStart = strStart + " 1/1/70";
strEnd = strEnd + " 1/1/70";
if(strStart.length && strEnd.length)
 {
   var timeStart = util.scand("h:MM tt m/d/yy", strStart);
   var timeEnd = util.scand("h:MM tt m/d/yy", strEnd);
   if (timeEnd < timeStart) {
   var strEnd = this.getField("stTime1.5").value
   var strEnd = strEnd + " 1/2/70";
   var timeEnd = util.scand("h:MM tt m/d/yy", strEnd);
   var diff = timeEnd - timeStart;
   var oneHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
   var timeleft = (diff/oneHour);
 }
 var diff = timeEnd - timeStart;
 var oneHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
 var timeleft = (diff/oneHour);
 event.value = timeleft.toFixed(2);

 } else {
 event.value = " ";
}
```